# How can root launch a regular Mac application from a cron job in /etc/crontab?

Tags: launchd, sudo, cron

I want the cronjob to do some things as the superuser, and depending on the result, launch an app as me, the logged-in user.

I've tried a bunch of things but nothing I think should work does.

Similar questions:

- [How can I execute sudo commands as a cron job?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27181/how-can-i-execute-sudo-commands-as-a-cron-job)
- [How can I automatically launch an application whenever the Mac goes idle?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39085/how-can-i-automatically-launch-an-application-whenever-the-mac-goes-idle)

Comment: Wow, over 1000 views and only 2 likes for the question and 1 for the answer?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the key was to use `su` with `-l`, `-c` and single quotes:

```
su -l myloginname -c '/usr/bin/open -a [App].app'
```

In context:

```
*/15 * * * * root if { !  /usr/bin/diff  /var/tmp/foo /var/backups/bar >> /var/log/foobar-diff.log ; } ; \
then  /usr/bin/su -l myloginname -c '/usr/bin/open -a /Applications/iProcrastinate.app > /dev/null 2> /dev/null' ; \
/bin/date >> /var/log/foobar-diff.log ; fi
```

Comment: To be a nitpicker, this is an UNIX-style solution: creating a launchd LaunchDaemon would be the ideal method (giving you the ability to easily suspend these launches and resume them on demand if such a need would arise, too) :)

Comment: You say 'UNIX-style solution' like it's a bad thing.  

IMO it's much easier to suspend these launches and resume them on demand by commenting and uncommenting the relevant line.  

I thought stackexchange wasn't the place for religious wars!

Comment: It isn't inherently a bad solution at all (just like I prefer manually created symlinks to Finder aliases); it's just a different way with some advantages and some disadvantages, almost like opening a currently selected file with Command+O, Command+Down, double clicking, the File menu or the contextual menu :)